# UPNP To Detect Devices in Network?

Tags: c++, networking, ip, router, upnp

I just finished understanding what's UPNP (universal plugs and play).
Now supposing it's enabled in my router, how can I used UPNP to detect devices connected to the network and analyzing it (it's a fridge, printer etc?)

I'm looking to work with C/C++ and not sure where to start from.

Answer (score 0):

UPnP is a collection of active and passive discovery protocols. Either hosts send advertising multicasts on their own, or they need to respond to search requests. Interested parties can then query the varies capabilities ("description") of a discovered service.

Hosts not directly supporting the required protocol cannot be discovered.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, what should I read? Any resources. I don't know where to start from. (Supposing host supports)